# entity manager doesn't have method getCriteriaBuilder()

Tags: jpa-2.0, entitymanager

I am introducing JPA2.0 in my application working on Oracle9i database and I added the libraries EclipseLink(JPA2.0) and created the entity classes but when I use

```
javax.persistence.criteria.CriteriaQuery cq = em.getCriteriaBuilder().createQuery();
```

I get the following error

cannot find symbol
symbol  : method getCriteriaBuilder()
location: interface javax.persistence.EntityManager

my web.xml is version 2.4 and here's my persistence.xml

```
<persistence version="2.0" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_0.xsd">
   <persistence-unit name="MiraclinPU" transaction-type="JTA">
    <jta-data-source>jdbc/Miraclin</jta-data-source>
    <exclude-unlisted-classes>false</exclude-unlisted-classes>
    <properties/>
   </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

It looks like the app is using JPA1.0 as I read on the forums...Can anyone help?

Comment: find a jar named persistence-1.0.jar or similar, remove it from the classpath and replace it with one called persistence-2.0.jar or similar. that's all

Comment: I found it in a huge JasperLib ejb3-persistence.jar, I removed the entire library and it worked...thanks.

Comment: Nice. Now you should write that as an answer and accept that answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Search in all libraries that are included in your project, and remove the ones containing persistence.xml except the one you need. Then reinclude them again.

Answer (score 5):

Use:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-jpa-2.0-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    </dependency>
```

And not:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.persistence</groupId>
        <artifactId>persistence-api</artifactId>
        <version>1.0.2</version>
    </dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

In eclipse:

- Project -> Properties -> Java Build Path -> Configure Build Path -> Libraries
- remove references to javax/persistente
- insert a reference to hibernate-jpa-2.0-api-/*version*/.jar

how to verify:

in your sourceDAO.java press <kbd>F3</kbd> in EntityManagerFactory and look what .jar eclipse open.

Answer (score 0):

Missing

```
import javax.persistence.criteria.*;
```

possibly?

Answer (score 0):

[Due to](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core) `org.hibernate.orm` artifact was moved to `hibernate-core`;
I removed this from `pom.xml`:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

and added this:

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.hibernate/hibernate-core -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
    <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
    <version>5.4.9.Final</version>
</dependency>
```

That was solved the `cannot find symbol getCriteriaBuilder()` problem.